# Auto mapping target fields from source in informatica

Tags: etl, informatica-powercenter, informatica

I hav a source structure in informatica like

```
col1 number   col2 varchar(40)   col3 DATE   col4 varchar(50)   col5 number
```

and my target definition is like

```
col4 varchar(50)   col1 number  col5 number  col3 varchar(40)  col3 DATE
```

If i want to load the source records into target i will map the columns appropriately from source to target in a zig zag way

I just want to know that if there is any concept like informatica will automap fields from source to target based on column names i.e if the target columns are shuffled but the column names are the same ...

any suggestions regarding the same would be helpful ..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PowerCenter can automatically link ports between transformations both **by position** and **by name**.

You should use the latter:

1. click `Layout` > `Autolink by Name`,
2. select the mapping object that you want to link (e.g. source) and drag the selected ports to another mapping object (e.g. target).

Comment: Thanks !! It was helpful....

Will this option also work for case sensitive fields ?

Comment: Informatica doesnt care about case sensitivity of fields.. therefore, you cant have two ports in a transformation like col1 and COL1.. they are one and the same...